# Is void() a valid C++ expression?

Tags: c++, expression, void

Apparently, this ternary expression with `void()` as one argument compiles:

```cpp
void foo() {}

//...
a == b ? foo() : void();
```

Is `void()` a valid expression by the standard, or is it just a compiler thing? If it's valid, then what kind of expression is it?

Comment: This is just someone trying to be smart. `if(a==b){ foo(); }` is clearer and has the same effect.

Comment: @CássioRenan your version can't be used in an expression though .

Comment: @M.M yes, but I really can't think of any useful way this could be used on an expression either, seeing that you cannot create objects of type `void`. (Although I will be the first to say that me not being able to think of one doesn't mean it can't exist)

Comment: Maybe it could occur in a parameter pack expansion, or some template metaprogramming where `void` came from a template type and this expression is argument to another function call

Comment: @M.M you can't pass `void()` as an argument.

Comment: @CássioRenan: Possible usage of `void()`: with SFINAE: `template <typename T> auto bar(T t) -> decltype(func(t), void())` (return type is `void`) Or to handle evil overload of comma operator: `(f1(t), void(), f2(t))`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I never argued that `void()` is not useful. I know it is very useful in metaprogramming (that's why `std::void_t` is a thing). I'm arguing specifically about `a==b?foo():void()`. If you were to put this expression in `decltype`, for instance, then you don't really need the ternary operator, since neither the boolean expression will be checked, nor `foo()` actually be called. Same for handling of comma operator.

Comment: @CássioRenan: It would be `decltype(a == b ? foo() : void())` versus `decltype(a==b, void(), foo(), void())` (former is shorter even if I prefer the later).

Comment: What's the point of answering the same question so many times when we have duplicate system?

Answer (score 21):

`void()` is a valid expression and yields a prvalue of type `void`.  In C++ 20 this will be expanded to also include `void{}`.  The relevant section for this is [[expr.type.conv]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type.conv#2)

> If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent to the corresponding cast expression. Otherwise, if the type is `cv void` and the initializer is `()` or `{}` (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a prvalue of the specified type that performs no initialization. Otherwise, the expression is a prvalue of the specified type whose result object is direct-initialized with the initializer. If the initializer is a parenthesized optional expression-list, the specified type shall not be an array type.

Comment: So, `void{}` should compile but it doesn't. According to [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1114r0.html#2351) it should. But why it doesn't?

Comment: @NutCracker It's only valid in C++20.  Not all compilers have caught up yet.  C++20 hasn't even been finalized .

Comment: @NutCracker No problem.  It is a needed addition to try and make uniform initialization more uniform.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to other answers, from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Void_type):

> **void** - type with an empty set of values. It is an incomplete type that
>   cannot be completed (consequently, objects of type void are
>   disallowed). There are no arrays of void, nor references to void.
>   However, pointers to void and functions returning type void
>   (procedures in other languages) are permitted.

This means that you can initialize your void type to any value `a == b ? foo()  : void(1)` or `a == b ? foo() : void(1111)` but it will perform nothing and would still compile successfully.